# Gradle signing plugin issue - unsigned jar and .asc file created

Tags: java, gradle, signing, jar-signing

I've generated my PGP private/public key pair and configured ~/.gradle/gradle.properties with the key information. Added the Gradle signing plugin to my build.gradle

```
plugins {
...
    id 'signing'
}

signing {
    sign jar
}
```

signJar task results in an unsigned jar along with an .asc file. Gradle version is 7.5.1.

Any ideas? or working example?

Comment: What task do you run? Can you add the console output?

Comment: As in the above description the task is signJar, there is no error logged, there is successful task completion but when checking the generated jar it is unsigned.